# 'is true' or 'are true'?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading a powerpoint for one of my classes and came across this sentence:

> It allows us to assert that exactly one of two propositions **is** true

When I first read it, I thought that it should have said:

> It allows us to assert that exactly one of two propositions **are** true

Since propositions is plural I would argue that *are* is the better fit in this sentence, but it is possible that *is* fits grammatically as well?

Answer (score 2):

We are asserting that only one proposition is true, not that both are.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are deconstructing the sentence a little too myopically.

The subject of the verb "is" is the phrase "exactly one of two propositions",
which is singular.

Comment: I've made a correction, please check to see that you agree.